# extjs float an image above another image in a dataview

Tags: extjs, dataview

I am making a preview in extjs and I need to float images above an image in a `DataView` based on an image clicked in another `DataView`. image layering. How does one do that?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can achieve that by manipulating the zIndex of the individual images... That is a CSS solution... The images you want above should have zIndex higher than the one below and at first hide all images except the lowermost image and then as required show the other images one after another... Hope it helps...